# App rejected by app store By Meta Data

Tags: ios, app-store

Following description, they have given but I don't know what was the exact issue.

Apr 11, 2018 at 11:18 PM
From Apple
2. 3 Performance: Accurate Metadata
Guideline 2.3.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

We noticed that your screenshots under 12.9 size do not sufficiently reflect your app in use as only one was submitted.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your screenshots to ensure that they accurately reflect the app in use on the supported devices. For iPhone, you need a set of 5.5-inch display screenshots and for iPad, you need a set for 12.9-inch display. This set will be scaled appropriately down to other device sizes when viewed on the App Store in each territory.

Resources

For resources on creating great screenshots for the App Store, you may want to review the App Store Product Page information available on the Apple developer portal.

Please ensure you have made any screenshot modifications using Media Manager. You should confirm your app looks and behaves identically in all languages and on all supported devices. Learn how to use Media Manager to add custom screenshots for each display size and localization.

Since your iTunes Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit iTunes Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all app localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing more detail on your app and the screen shots in question, but the rejection message from Apple seems pretty clear; You need to accurately reflect your app in use on an iPad in your 12.9" screenshots and provide more than 1

Comment: You don't know the exact issue? "*your screenshots ... do not sufficiently reflect your app ... as only one was submitted.*" You need more screenshots to better reflect your app. I don't think they can make it much clearer than that. They even tell you that "*For iPhone, you need a set of 5.5-inch display screenshots and for iPad, you need a set for 12.9-inch display*".

Comment: @ObsidianAge  am i need to upload Every screenshot in both languages

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple App Store Policies instead of directly about programming and coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do not sufficiently reflect your app in use as only one was submitted.

You need more screenshots. I suggest three or four, more if it's a larger app.

Comment: Previously they accepted one screenshot but this time they asking more And also they are saying localization

Comment: Right, so if you know what they are asking for, why are you asking a question here?

Comment: They are Mentioned something like localization in Note

Comment: As this answer states, you need more images. The extra information just says that you don't need to resubmit your application, rather that you simply need to adjust your metadata. The note simply states that if you have multiple localisations (like different languages for different countries), then you'll need to add the new screenshots to each localisation.